# Hyperledger composer-rest-server to have multiple cards associated

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have five node and each node have a single user and i need to host an single rest server which can contains all the five user cards with in a single port.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: By user you mean organizations ? or do you mean that at each node (your pc) there is a card stored ?

Comment: Have you investigated the multi-user mode of the REST server documented in the Composer docs.
But if you want more help you need to describe your problem in more details.